# Mobx's observable loses child objects equality

Tags: javascript, mobx

When I create an observable from plain object which contains fields that are effectively same objects, this property are not equal objects anymore. So if I change one's property, the second stay untouched.

Is there a proper way to handle this?

```js
import { observable } from "mobx";

const status = { id: "some-obj" };

const obj = {
  status,
  status2: status
};

const observableObj = observable(obj);

const isEqual = observableObj.status2 === observableObj.status;

document.body.innerHTML = `Is equal = ${isEqual}`;
console.log(observableObj);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-equality-demo-5eowk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `observable` on regular object it does not mutate it, but creates new observable object. And MobX does it recursively on every inner object or value, so that's why `observableObj.status2` and `observableObj.status` are not equal. They were created from same "blueprint" object, but each is independent copy, if I can say so.

Original `status` is still regular object, and `status2` became observable object inside `observableObj`. Hope it makes sense.

What you can do is just make `status` observable by it self, before passing it inside `obj`, like so:

```js
const status = observable({ id: "some-obj" });

const obj = {
  status,
  status2: status
};

const observableObj = observable(obj);

observableObj.status2 === observableObj.status // => true
```

That way Mobx is not going to do anything on it since it is already an `observable`.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions64032286-rxj5m?file=/index.js